# Transform links to files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I had two solutions, lets call them A and B. A was the original one so when I developed B I created some links to files in solution A.

Now I want to erase A and transform all links in solution B into actual files so I have one unique solution.

The only solution I found to this is erasing each link one by one and replacing it with the linked file.

Is there a way to do this automatically and with the entire solution at once?

Comment: You don't have to do them one by one, you can select multiple links, delete them, then do "Add existing item" and select multiple files to add. How could this be any faster?

Comment: With a tool or plugin that detects which file is pointing the link to, and replaces them :P

Comment: Have you got so many and do this so often that it saves so much time? Between us we already wasted enough time to have done it manually ;-)

Comment: jajajajja they are indeed A LOT of files but probably you are right and I'm just very lazy.

Comment: Then get off StackOverflow and do some work! ;-))

Comment: And by "A LOT" I mean hundreds of files spread over hundreds of folders XD